# Why nothing is appearing on Screen and how to solve this issue while using RecyclerView in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

after 2 hours of watching tutorial on RecyclerView I just stuck on the blank Screen. I just want that my code runs and I get the required Output. Also I need some information about cardView. Any help would be appreciated.

here is my code

**Adapter.java**

```
package bhanu13.flyourskills;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.Image;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private final LayoutInflater inflator;
    List<RowContent> data= Collections.emptyList();

    public Adapter(Context context,List<RowContent> data) {
        this.data=data;
       inflator=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view=inflator.inflate(R.layout.one_row,parent,false);
        MyViewHolder myViewHolder=new MyViewHolder(view);
        return myViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.firstImageButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.himi);
        holder.secondImageButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.himi);
        holder.textView.setText("A");

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }
    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        ImageButton firstImageButton;
        ImageButton secondImageButton;
        TextView textView;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            firstImageButton= (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.first_image_button);
            secondImageButton= (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.second_image_button);
            textView= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview);
        }
    }
}
```

**Fregment's code**

```
package bhanu13.flyourskills;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ButtonsFregment extends Fragment {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    Adapter adapter;
    ImageButton firstImageButton;
    ImageButton secondImageButton;
    Context context;
    private List<RowContent> data;


    public ButtonsFregment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_buttons_fregment, container, false);
        recyclerView= (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        adapter=new Adapter(getActivity(),getData());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        return view;
    }

    public List<RowContent> getData() {
        List<RowContent> rowContents=new ArrayList<>();
        RowContent rowContent=new RowContent();
        rowContent.firstImageID=R.drawable.himi;
        rowContent.secondImageID=R.drawable.himi;
        rowContents.add(rowContent);

        return rowContents;
    }
}
```

**One_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/first_image_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/second_image_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="dummy"
        android:id="@+id/textview"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**and Fragment's xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ButtonsFregment">
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package bhanu13.flyourskills;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            Fragment buttonsFragment = new ButtonsFregment();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.linear_fragments, buttonsFragment).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: REcycler view needs to have match_parent attribute or specific size. It is a kid of a scroll view, you can't expect it will wrap all the views.

Comment: As you asked to do, I changed the recyclerView layout height to android:layout_height="match_parent" but nothing happens @SzymonKlimaszewski

Comment: are you getting any text in those recyclerview textview or not?

Comment: I am not getting anything. Only white screen is here.@AnimeshJena

Comment: Hmm, i don't see problem. Set up a few debug points in adapter (like at getItemCount()) and debug the app. Also, are you sure you are showing this fragment?

Comment: In the Adapter.java, can you just replace   List<RowContent> data; in place of   List<RowContent> data= Collections.emptyList(); and see whats happening?

Comment: I debug the program but does not get required output. Actually gets nothing @Gudin

Comment: Nothing Happens @AnimeshJena

Comment: Are debug points even called? In that case you are probably not showing fragment on the screen. Did you make fragment transaction or XML your fragment into activity?

Comment: yes, I did use Fragment transaction object. ActuallyI first use simple Fragments and It works fine for me. But then I used the Recycler view and everything is gone.

Comment: Please try the below thing once. Inside the onCreateViewHolder() method, in place of  View view=inflator.inflate(R.layout.one_row,parent,false); just type   "  View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
        .inflate(R.layout.one_row, viewGroup, false);

Comment: @AnkitArora can you edit your post and add code of fragment transaction?

Comment: Nothing happens @AnimeshJena

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activity

```
package com.example.usmank.myapplication;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ProgressDialog pd=new ProgressDialog(this, ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        pd.show();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.framLayout,new YourFragment());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        if(pd.isShowing()) {
        pd.dismiss();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

fragment

```
package com.example.usmank.myapplication;

/**
 * Created by usmank on 3/8/2016.
 */
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

 public class YourFragment extends Fragment {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    Adapter adapter;
    ImageButton firstImageButton;
    ImageButton secondImageButton;
    Context context;


    public YourFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_buttons_fragment, container, false);
        recyclerView= (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        adapter=new Adapter(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        return view;
    }


}
```

adapter

```
package com.example.usmank.myapplication;

/**
 * Created by usmank on 3/8/2016.
 */
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.Image;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private final LayoutInflater inflator;

    public Adapter(Context context) {
        inflator=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view=inflator.inflate(R.layout.one_row,parent,false);
        MyViewHolder myViewHolder=new MyViewHolder(view);
        return myViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.firstImageButton.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        holder.secondImageButton.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        holder.textView.setText("A");

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        //data.size()
        return 10;
    }
    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        ImageButton firstImageButton;
        ImageButton secondImageButton;
        TextView textView;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            firstImageButton= (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.first_image_button);
            secondImageButton= (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.second_image_button);
            textView= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview);
        }
    }
}
```

fragment xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ButtonsFregment">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

recycler xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/first_image_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/second_image_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="dummy"
        android:id="@+id/textview"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

activty xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/framLayout">

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

gredle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.usmank.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

Comment: please run as such then change accordingly you want also look fragment's import

Comment: yeah, I recognize that you used support library fragment and I used simple one but it didn't make any differance.

Answer (score 0):

I am using like this it is working perfectly please change according to your requirments

Recycler Adapter is

```
    package adapter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.mycompany.locationsharing.R;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import common.CommUtil;
import common.SendNotifications;


/**
 * Created by usmank on 1/15/2016.
 */
public class FriendsListsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FriendsListsAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private  final Activity activity;
    private  final JSONArray arrayFriendList;
    private static final String TAG="MY_FRIEND_ID";
    private FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    private LatLng mLatLng;

    public FriendsListsAdapter(Activity activity, JSONArray arrayFriendList,LatLng mLatLng) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.arrayFriendList = arrayFriendList;
        this.mLatLng = mLatLng;
    }


    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private final TextView friendsName;
        private final ImageView ivFriendImage;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            friendsName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvFriendsName);
            ivFriendImage= (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivFriendsImage);
            v.setClickable(true);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, viewGroup, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(view);
        return vh;

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
        try {
            viewHolder.friendsName.setText(arrayFriendList.getJSONObject(i).get("name").toString());
            Picasso.with(activity).load("https://graph.facebook.com/"+ arrayFriendList.getJSONObject(i).get("id").toString()+"/picture")
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).resize(160, 170).into(viewHolder.ivFriendImage);
            CommUtil.showDebugLogs(TAG,arrayFriendList.getJSONObject(i).get("id").toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
           CommUtil.showExceptionTrace(e);
        }
        viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    SendNotifications sendNotifications = new SendNotifications(activity,arrayFriendList.getJSONObject(i).get("name").toString());
                    String[] parems = {arrayFriendList.getJSONObject(i).get("id").toString(),String.valueOf(mLatLng.latitude),String.valueOf(mLatLng.longitude)};
                    sendNotifications.execute(parems);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    CommUtil.showExceptionTrace(e);
                }

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayFriendList.length();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }
}
```

and where i am using this

```
recyclerFriendList.setAdapter(new FriendsListsAdapter(getActivity(), friendsJsonArray,new LatLng(latitude,longitude)));
```

and recycler_item.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="10dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:paddingRight="7dp"
            android:id="@+id/ivFriendsImage"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/tvFriendsName"
            android:text="Hello My Friend"
            android:textColor="#000"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

and where recycler view is used

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerFriendsList"
        android:background="#e7e7e7"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

and please also in import recycler library
and carview is also used in it which is the component of material design which can be used to beautify

Comment: I used the library and I don't see anything useful in your Answer

Comment: it is working fine please just change according to your logic

Comment: Its not working @Nisar Ahmed. If it works fine then you don't see me here

Comment: there is a issue in your fragment transaction please can you tell me why you use loop and if necessary then use fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.linear_fragments, buttonsFragment).commit(); not add it will work

Comment: I am using the loop here because recycler View is in my fragment and I want to use fragment multiple times.

Comment: hehe it is not working as you are doing please remove loop you should study fragment and please copy my code as it and put your logic it that

Comment: please use my code and put your logic in it you will save your time

Comment: It does not have any error. It works fine but only white screen appears

Comment: use inflater as                                                                                                 @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, viewGroup, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(view);
        return vh;

    }

Comment: Nothing happens.@ Nasir

Comment: class RowContent {int firstImageButton; int secondImageButton;}

Comment: I am posting another in which i run your code completely and remove all errors